# Sort object array by looking at another array order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sort an object array by looking at another arrays order, my first array is something like this

```
["HV001O3XL", "HV001OSML", "HV001OLGE"]
```

and my object array is like :

```
[{productcode: "HV001OSML", price: 6, qty: "2", desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN", stock: "138"},{productcode: "HV001OLGE", price: 6, qty: "1", desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN", stock: "271"},{productcode: "HV001O3XL", price: 6, qty: "1", desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN", stock: "1112"}]
```

I would like to re-shuffle the object array so that the object.productcode matched the first array, HV001O3XL being first instead of HV001OSML etc. Is this possible in angular or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const objs = [
 {
  productcode: "HV001OSML",
  price: 6,
  qty: "2",
  desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN",
  stock: "138"
 },
 {
  productcode: "HV001OLGE",
  price: 6,
  qty: "1",
  desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN",
  stock: "271"
 },
 {
  productcode: "HV001O3XL",
  price: 6,
  qty: "1",
  desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN",
  stock: "1112"
 }
];
const result = [
 "HV001O3XL",
 "HV001OSML",
 "HV001OLGE"
].map((key) => objs.find(item => item.productcode === key));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it adds the same object twice so it ends up [{productcode: "HV001OLGE", price: 6, qty: "2", desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN", stock: "271"},{productcode: "HV001OLGE", price: 6, qty: "2", desc: "HV001 WAISTCOAT ORN", stock: "271"}]

Comment: @GazSmith If you run this code here, it don't create doubles.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const orders = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let objects = [{
    code: 'd'
}, {
    code: 'c'
}, {
    code: 'a',
}, {
    code: 'b'
}]

objects.sort((a, b) => orders.indexOf(a.code) - orders.indexOf(b.code));
console.log(objects);
```